Plotting Multiple Unrelated Datasets Algebra of Graphics
I want to plot multiple, somewhat unrelated datasets on one graph using algebra of graphics.
i.e. I want some of the lines dashed, others dotted.
Colors can random that is fine.
Ideally I would have custom labels for each item.
I have been trying to achieve this, by creating a data object for each dataset and applying layers to it, but I am not sure how to make that work with having a nice legend.
Plus this does not seem like a natural way to do this, using algebra of graphics functionality.
function filterPlot(filterPos; xlab = "", ylab="Blocking Intensity")
    
    dataForPlot = nothing
    vec_to_df((id, values)) = DataFrame(label = id, xx = 1:length(values), yy = values)
    
    #filterPos is generaly a vector of vectors. We want to plot each of the vectors. 
    if filterPos[1] isa Array{<:Number,1}
        counterj=1
        dataForPlot = data(DataFrame(xx = 1:length(filterPos[1]), yy = filterPos[1]))*mapping(:1=>(t->t) ,:2 => (t->t))* visual( color = ColorSchemes.twelvebitrainbow[counterj])
        for thing in filterPos[2:end]
            counterj+=1
            plotFilter = DataFrame(xx = 1:length(thing), yy = thing)
            dataForPlot =dataForPlot + data(plotFilter)*mapping(:1=>(t->t) ,:2 => (t->t))*visual(color = ColorSchemes.twelvebitrainbow[counterj])
        end
        
    else
        plotFilter = DataFrame(xx = 1:length(filterPos), yy = filterPos)
        dataForPlot = data(plotFilter)*mapping(:xx=>(t->t) ,:yy => (t->t))
        
    end
    dataForPlot *= visual(Lines)


    plaxis = (xlabel = xlab, ylabel = ylab)

    drawing = draw(dataForPlot;axis = plaxis)
    return drawing
end 

edit: typo in code

Does this answer your question? Colouring different datasets Algebra of Graphics (Julia)

@PaSTE Not entirely. I have seen that answer. It really only gives control over colours. Ideally I would also be able to set custom line styles for each line and a custom label for each line (not just 1,2,3).
I think that answer would allow me to edit the labels by giving the right headers in the data frame, but not so sure about line styles.

The following plotting set up allows to individually vary colours and styles of the appearance of each data set on the plot as I wanted in the original question.
(So really I already just settled for the solution given in my question, just cleaned it up a bit)
Suppose I have my data stored as vectors of vectors:
#My x values:
xdatas = [ xvalues1, xvalues2 ]

ydatas = [yvalues1, yvalues2]

myColor = anyColorSchemeILike
colorLength = length(myColor)


vec_to_df(j) = DataFrame(xx = xdatas[j], yy = ydatas[j])

dataForPlot = data(vec_to_df(1))*mapping(:xx, :yy)*visual(color = myColor[ 1 ]  )

for j in 2:length(xdatas)
      dataForPlot += data(vec_to_df(j))*mapping(:xx, :yy) *visual(color = myColor[ mod(j-1,colorLength-1)+1   ]  )
end

actualFigure = Figure()

draw!(actualFigure[1,1], dataForPlot )


Is this a solution? Or a further requirement? Your wording is unclear, and without further explanation so is the answer—if that’s what this is.
